# Bash скрипт. Соединение с удаленным MySQL сервером, и отправка запросов. Как реализовать?

Tags: bash, mysql

**Дано:** Debian, Apache + PHP + MySQL, Bash скрипт.

**Требуется:** Из **bash** скрипта соединиться с **удаленным** **MySQL** **сервером**, и выполнить определенный запрос. Ключевое слово здесь "удаленным", так как соединятся надо именно с сервером, который находится на другой машинке!

Comment: Из man mysql

      --host=host_name, -h host_name

      Connect to the MySQL server on the given host.

Comment: mysql -h dbhostaddress -D dbname -e 'SELECT * FROM test;'

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Еще вопросик возник, 
mysql -h HOST -u USER_NAME -D DB_NAME -e 'UPDATE *DATA HERE etc..*;'

Правильно ли составлен? И как пароль вписать?
в man написано -p[pass], не совсем пойму как это. В квадратных скобках?

Comment: man mysql

     shell> mysql --user=user_name --password=your_password db_name

     
    --password[=password], -p[password]

           The password to use when connecting to the server. If you use the short option form (-p), you cannot have a
           space between the option and the password. If you omit the password value following the --password or -p option
           on the command line, mysql prompts for one.


Написано, что Вы **не можете** ставить пробел между -p и паролем. Но можно было использовать длинную форму `--password=`

Comment: Спасибо еще раз)

Answer (score 1):

пример из [документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html):

```
$ mysql --host=remote.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Если порт на удаленном сервере открыт для нас, достаточно указывать имя/адрес удаленного сервера при соединии: `mysql --host …`

Если порт закрыт, но есть доступ по ssh, мапим порт, затем соединяемся как если бы сервер был локальным: `ssh -f -N -L 1111:remote.com:3306` затем `mysql --host 127.0.0.1 -port 1111 …`

Или просто удаленно запускаем консоль mysql и говорим что ей делать:
`ssh remote.com 'mysql -uuser -ppass -e "USE test; SHOW TABLES;"'`

Ссылки:

- http://www.laurencegellert.com/2011/01/command-line-ssh-tunnel-port-forwarding/
- https://serverfault.com/questions/499415/running-a-remote-sql-query-over-ssh